# How can I fix the outline not always being on top

Tags: html, css

At the moment, I'm trying to create an inline set of `<a>` tags which look like buttons. The buttons are styled to have a border around them at all times, but I've had to set `margin-left: -1px` to ensure that the border 'collapses' like with tables.

Everything works apart from when the button has `:focus` as I want to put an outline around the `<a>`. As the image below shows, the outline is perfect apart from the right-hand edge which is hidden.

[image]

I'm trying to create a nice styled pagination control. The buttons are laid out as follows:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Does anyone have any idea why this might happen and how I can remedy it?

**Note**: I am limited to the amount of code I can provide as it is production code. I will attempt to give as much information as people require ad hoc.

Comment: Why not just drop this disgraceful margin-left and remove the left border (except on last item) ? That would solve the outline issue and your CSS would be cleaner. As a side remark, please note that semantically speaking a pagination should use a `ol` , not a `ul` .

Comment: Have you tried modifying the z-index (CSS) of the element ? It might help the HTML element te be placed "over" the others.

Comment: @Bartdude, thank you for your comment. I have done both using `margin-left: -1px` and removing the left border. Neither does anything.

Comment: @Knak, I have tried using z-index, but I fear there's either something more to it that I'm not using or that it simply doesn't work.

Comment: @NathanWhite `z-index: 1` and `position: relative` on `a:focus`

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan could you please post that as an answer so I can mark it? That did the trick perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: I think the answer  should be assigned to @Knack, basically he had the idea first

Comment: @Knak, would you mind writing an answer out so that I might mark it as correct? Fabrizio Calderan has kindly passed the flame to you.

Comment: yes: “_With high speed comes high responsibilities_” ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Workaround to the button outline on focus appearing behind the sibling button with float left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16288444/workaround-to-the-button-outline-on-focus-appearing-behind-the-sibling-button-wi)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue can be solved playing with the `z-index` CSS property of HTML elements.

In that particular case, using `z-index: 1` and `position: relative` on `a:focus` will give the correct display.

Thanks to @FabrizioCalderan for the final answer.